# Kafka Exactly once with Transactional Producer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am trying to understand Kafka exactly once using Transactional producer/consumer.

I came across the below example. But, still I have hard time in understanding exactly once. Is this code correct?

> producer.sendOffsetsToTransaction  - What this code does? Should this be done to the same target topic?

What is system crashes before consumer.commitSync(); // The same messages will be read again and duplicate messages will be produced?

```
public class ExactlyOnceLowLevel {

    public void runConsumer() throws Exception {
        final KafkaConsumer<byte[], byte[]> consumer = createConsumer();
        final Producer<Long, String> producer = createProducer();

        producer.initTransactions();

        consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(TOPIC));

        while (true) {
            final ConsumerRecords<byte[], byte[]> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));

            try {
                final Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> currentOffsets = new HashMap<>();
                producer.beginTransaction();
                for (final ConsumerRecord<byte[], byte[]> record : records) {
                    System.out.printf("Received Message topic =%s, partition =%s, offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s\n", record.topic(), record.partition(),
                                record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());

                    final ProducerRecord<Long, String> producerRecord =
                                new ProducerRecord<>(TOPIC_1, new BigInteger(record.key()).longValue(), record.value().toString());
                    // send returns Future
                    final RecordMetadata metadata = producer.send(producerRecord).get();
                    currentOffsets.put(new TopicPartition(TOPIC_1, record.partition()), new OffsetAndMetadata(record.offset()));
                }
                producer.sendOffsetsToTransaction(currentOffsets, "my-transactional-consumer-group"); // a bit annoying here to reference group id rwice
                producer.commitTransaction();
                consumer.commitSync();
                currentOffsets.clear();
                // EXACTLY ONCE!
            }
            catch (ProducerFencedException | OutOfOrderSequenceException | AuthorizationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                // We can't recover from these exceptions, so our only option is to close the producer and exit.
                producer.close();
            }
            catch (final KafkaException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                // For all other exceptions, just abort the transaction and try again.
                producer.abortTransaction();
            }
            finally {
                producer.flush();
                producer.close();
            }
        }
    }

    private static KafkaConsumer<byte[], byte[]> createConsumer() {
        final Properties consumerConfig = new Properties();
        consumerConfig.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS);
        consumerConfig.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "my-group");
        consumerConfig.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false");
        consumerConfig.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        consumerConfig.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, LongDeserializer.class.getName());

        consumerConfig.put(ConsumerConfig.ISOLATION_LEVEL_CONFIG, IsolationLevel.READ_COMMITTED); // this has to be

        return new KafkaConsumer<>(consumerConfig);
    }

    private static Producer<Long, String> createProducer() {
        final Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, LongDeserializer.class.getName());

        props.put(ProducerConfig.ENABLE_IDEMPOTENCE_CONFIG, "true");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, 3); // this is now safe !!!!
        props.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all"); // this has to be all
        props.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_IN_FLIGHT_REQUESTS_PER_CONNECTION, 1); // this has to be 1

        return new KafkaProducer<>(props);
    }

    public static void main(final String... args) throws Exception {

        final ExactlyOnceLowLevel example = new ExactlyOnceLowLevel();
        example.runConsumer();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not attempt to commit offsets with the Consumer when using the read/process/write pattern with Kafka Transactions. As you hinted this can cause issues.

In this use case, offsets need to be added to the transaction and you should only use `sendOffsetsToTransaction()` to do that. That method ensure that these offsets are only committed if the full transaction succeeds. See the [Javadoc](http://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html#sendOffsetsToTransaction-java.util.Map-java.lang.String-):

> Sends a list of specified offsets to the consumer group coordinator,
>   and also marks those offsets as part of the current transaction. These
>   offsets will be considered committed only if the transaction is
>   committed successfully. The committed offset should be the next
>   message your application will consume, i.e. lastProcessedMessageOffset
>   + 1.
>
> This method should be used when you need to batch consumed and
>   produced messages together, typically in a consume-transform-produce
>   pattern. Thus, the specified consumerGroupId should be the same as
>   config parameter group.id of the used consumer. Note, that the
>   consumer should have enable.auto.commit=false and should also not
>   commit offsets manually (via sync or async commits).

Comment: So, sendOffsetsToTransaction should be to the source topic. What if there are issues when calling currentOffsets.clear();?

Comment: In your example, you don't have to call `clear()` as you will be re-creating a fresh map when starting the next iteration. Even if you want to call `clear()` that happens after the transaction is committed, so no data is lost.

Comment: Do we need transactional consumer here.         consumerConfig.put(ConsumerConfig.ISOLATION_LEVEL_CONFIG, IsolationLevel.READ_COMMITTED); 
What role it plays here as it simply reads from other topic.

Comment: If the input topic does not contain any transactions, keep the default for this setting. If it does contain transactions, then that depends on your requirements.

Comment: producer.sendOffsetsToTransaction  -> Where this transaction offsets are stored? Is it __stransaction_state topic or in transaction commit log or ....

Comment: They are written to the `__consumer_offset` topic like normal offsets. But they will only be "visible" once the transaction is committed. If you want to understand how transactions work exactly, I recommend looking at the design document: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-98+-+Exactly+Once+Delivery+and+Transactional+Messaging

Comment: `sendOffsetsToTransaction()` how does the producer know what has been consumed, where o you get the offsets from as a producer...? Examples I find seem to assume you have an in-process consumer to reference, which seems like a poor assumption. Producer doesn't know about consumers that are running elsewear?